# Getting the stage to follow the players Y axis. (Flash As3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'll try my best to give you as much detail as I can.

I have created a platform game and I have already implemented movement and collision.

My game Loop runs this (I only have one eventListener)

```
    private function level1GameLoop():void
    {
        groundCollision();
        movementCode();
        scrollLevel();
    }
```

Ground collision takes care of making sure the player doesn't fall (ground is the level overall, apologies for the bad naming convention(s).

```
    private function groundCollision():void 
    {
        if (ground.bottom.hitTestPoint(character.x + 13, character.y, true || ground.bottom.hitTestPoint(character.x + 13, character.y, true)))
        {
            trace("h");
            while (ground.bottom.hitTestPoint(character.x + 13, character.y, true || ground.bottom.hitTestPoint(character.x + 13, character.y, true)))
            {
                character.incrementUp();
                if (ground.bottom.hitTestPoint(character.x + 13, character.y, true || ground.bottom.hitTestPoint(character.x + 13, character.y, true)))
                {
                }
                else{
                    character.keepOnGround();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and then you have your typical movement code

```
        else if (rightKey)
        {
            character.moveRight();
            lookingRight = true;
            lookingLeft = false;
        }
        else if (leftKey)
        {
            lookingLeft = true;
            lookingRight = false;
            character.moveLeft();
        }
```

Before scrolling the level, I tested to see does my character hit all of the platforms and yes he does.

So now I want to implement scrolling.

In the class definition I have set up a variable called container which is a sprite.

```
    private var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

I have then added my children on to the stage before starting the game loop

```
        addChild(container);
        container.addChild(ground);
        container.addChild(character);
        addChild(timerGIF);//this does not need to scroll
```

I have then tested the game again, and the collision works fine.

Now I have tried many attempts to scroll the player and keep him on center of the screen making sure that the collisions still function correctly.

private function scrollLevel():void 
        {

```
        /*
        _camera.x = character.x - stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
        _camera.y = character.y - stage.stageHeight * 0.5;
        //"camera" must not show areas outside of the game world
        if (_camera.x < 0) 
        {
            _camera.x = 0;
        }
        //Right
        if (_camera.x > (container.width) - stage.stageWidth) 
        {
            _camera.x = (container.width) - stage.stageWidth;
        }
        //Bottom
        if (_camera.y > (container.height) - stage.stageHeight) 
        {
            _camera.y = (container.height) - stage.stageHeight;
        }
        //Top
        if (_camera.y < 0) 
        {
            _camera.y = 0;
        }

        container.scrollRect = _camera;
        */

        //ground.x = -character.x + stage.stageWidth / 2;
    //  ground.y = -character.y + stage.stageHeight / 2;


            /*var offset:int = 10;
            var distance:Number = character.x - ((stage.stageWidth / 2) + offset);
            var distance2:Number = character.y - ((stage.stageHeight / 2));
            var ease:int = 5;
            if (distance < 0)
            {
                distance *= -1;
            }
            if (distance2 < 0)
            {
                distance2 *= -1;
            }
            if (character.x < (stage.stageWidth / 2))
            {
                var variable:int = distance / ease;
                //character.x += variable;
                container.x += variable;



            }
            if (character.x > (stage.stageWidth / 2))
            {
                var variable2:int = distance / ease;
                //character.x -= variable2;
                container.x -= variable2;


            }

            /*if (character.y < (stage.stageHeight / 2))
            {
                var variable3:int = distance2 / ease;
                character.y += variable3;
                //container.y += variable3;



            }

            if (character.y > (stage.stageHeight / 2))
            {
                var variable4:int = distance2 / ease;
                character.y -= variable4;
                //container.y -= variable4;

            }*/

            /*var camera:Point = new Point();

            // Set the camera coordinates to the char coordinates.
            camera.x = character.x;
            camera.y = character.y;

            // Adjust the world position on the screen based on the camera position.
            ground.x = -camera.x + (stage.stageWidth / 2);
            ground.y = -camera.y + (stage.stageHeight / 2);*/

    }
```

None of these seem to work, since the collision then gets all muddled up.

By this I mean, my character ends up floating, or falling through

Other things to mention, ground is a movie clip and is basically my level(once again, poor naming conventions, apoligiez).

Inside ground there are hitTest box's and objects that the character will get.

[image: Please Check]

Comment: You're doing this the very wrong and very slow way. You *should* move the character, and then move the parent container to reposition itself so that the character is on the centre of the screen. This is as simple as setting the parent position to the negative of the character position, plus the stage width and height.

Comment: I do this then? if player presses right key, move the player right then go to this function UpdatePosition(); UpdatePosition{ set containers.x to the container.characters.x?

Comment: Almost, set the container.x to `-` character.x. Do this for the y axis as well. So if the character is at 100, 200 the container should be -100, -200.

Comment: Marty, thank you. I am trying to alter the code. But my character.x is not walking for some reason. I.E his x position is not being shifted upon the key presses

Comment: @Marty I think I've got it! 

   if (rightKey)
   {
    _character.x += 3;
    container.x = - _character.x + stage.stageWidth/2;
   }

Comment: I don't understand why you have to move both?! Just split them (get the character out of the background), and simply move the background on user interaction: if key right -> move background 10px lef; if key up -> move background 10px down..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a great job, but in the very difficult way, first things first, you should know that when you want your character to move inside the container in a certain direction, you have to adjust all the other children of the container to move in the opposite direction, so it gives the feeling that the character moves in the desired direction.. this my friend is the hard way, and I think the reason made you go that way is that you want `timerGIF` to stay not changed all the time.. but this can be achieved in a very more easier way by reversing your code like that...

```
//reverse your strategy for coding:

var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(container);
addChild(ground);
addChild(character);
container.addChild(timerGIF);

//define some very imp vars that you will need to adjust for each level to
//prevent recoding in each level, just set the vars to the new level properties

var level_width:Number=1600;
var level_hight:Number=1200;
var screen_width:Number=800;
var screen_hight:Number=600;

//the ease of camera is the speed of camera, and whoever you want the camera to
//follow just pass it as a camera_target (that will be in this case your character)

var camera_speed:Number=5;
var camera_target:Object=charachter;

//then add your scroll function (named hear as camera();)

function camera(wide, high, target, speed) {
  if (target!=null) {
      cam_x = ((screen_width/2)-target.x-x)/speed;
      cam_y = ((screen_hight/2)-target.y-y)/speed;
      x+=cam_x;
      y+=cam_y;
  }
  if (x>0) {
      x=0;
  }
  if (x<wide*-0.5) {
      x=- wide/2;
  }
  if (y>0) {
      y=0;
  }
  if (y<high*-0.5) {
      y=- high/2;
  }
  //now the code to keep container and all its children not scrolled is just:
  container.x=- x;
  container.y=- y;
}
```

Finally put this following line in your `level1GameLoop()` replacing `scrollLevel();`

```
function level1GameLoop():void
{
    groundCollision();
    movementCode();
    //scrollLevel();
    camera (level_width, level_hight, camera_target, camera_speed);
}
```

Have a nice day sir...

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, is for starling, but the you can use the logic

http://wiki.starling-framework.org/extensions/fluocam